# Android Studio Giraffe Not running

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded the zip version of Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1.19.
It extracted without any issues. When I ran studio64.exe / studio.exe i get the following error window.
[image]

The error text is available below

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.atlassian.bitbucket.linky.stats.LinkyAnalyticsService' [Plugin: com.atlassian.bitbucket.references]
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:571)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:59)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:154)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance$lambda$1(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:133)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.computeInNonCancelableSection(Cancellation.java:99)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:132)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:92)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:77)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:392)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$initApplicationImpl$appInitializedListeners$1$1$2$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:139)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:788)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:758)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javaClass.classLoader
…m("/META-INF/plugin.xml") must not be null
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.linky.stats.LinkyAnalyticsService.(analytics.kt:28)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:54)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:996)
at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:36)
... 25 more

---

Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
E:\AndroidStudio_2022.3.1.19\android-studio\jbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a issue with the Bitbucket plugin. This happened only on my current system. So I followed the suggestions from the Google known issues section. I reset all the plugins.
[Shown Here: Known issues with Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues?authuser=1#studio-config-directories)

Now it started properly.

Answer (score 0):

**If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.**

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

For Android Studio 4.0 and earlier:

Windows: %HOMEPATH%.AndroidStudio\config
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name.AndroidStudio3.6\config

macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.6

Linux: ~/.AndroidStudio/config
Example: ~/.AndroidStudio3.6/config